# What is wrong with this simple jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

This is a simple jQuery code, what I want to do is hide `#bling`, but it does not

```
<script language="javascript">

 $("document").ready(function() {  

      $('#bling').hide();  


  }); 

</script>

<div id="bling" style="background-color:#FFFF66; width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
```

Thanks
Dave

Comment: This shouldn't affect this piece of code, but language should probably be somethinglike `language="text/javascript"`

Comment: That code works fine in Firefox and IE8.  Are you sure you have Jquery loaded?

Comment: @anonymous: the value for the language property is correct. It is however better to use type="text/javascript"

Answer (score 9):

Change `$("document")` to `$(document)`

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your HTML?

Comment: '<script language="javascript">
        
 $(document).ready(function() {  

           $("#bling").hide():
      
         });      

</script>

<div id="bling" style="background-color:#FFFF99; width:200px; height:100px;">test</div>'

Check the above out

Answer (score 3):

I tested the code, and it works fine, eventhough you have the string `"document"` instead of `document` and an ancient `language` attribute on the script tag...

Use `type="text/javascript"` on the script tag. You can just send a function to the jQuery object as a shortcut for using the ready function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
   $('#bling').hide();
});

</script>
```

However, as it's not this code that is the problem, there is something else in your page that is causing it.

- Check that you have successfully included the jQuery script.
- Check that you don't have another element with the id "bling". An id has to be unique in the page.
- Check for Javascript error messages. In IE check the status bar for a notification. In Firefox open the Javascript console.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me as it is .
Try using jquery from jquery site, the code is below.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">

 $("document").ready(function() {  

      $('#bling').hide();  


  }); 

</script>

<div id="bling" style="background-color:#FFFF66; width:100px; height:100px;">aaaaaaaa</div>
```

See if it works.

Comment: Note: It's not including the script from the jQuery site, it's including it from the Google site.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

$("document").ready(function() {

//..to..

$(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including the jQuery core javascript file in your HTML. On top of that, your code should look more like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#bling').hide();  
}); 
</script>
```

Note the `type` attribute on the script tag as well as `document` not in quotes.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><br />

$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('#album_result').hide();
  

 });      
</script>


<div id="album_result" style="background-color:#FFFF99; width:200px; height:100px;">test</div>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jQuery is loading:

```
<script language="javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {  

      alert('Can you hear me now?');
      //$('#bling').hide();  


  }); 

</script>
```